# Using d3-windbarb (npm) in icon style of VectorLayer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, style, vector-layer, d3

I was trying to have a vector layer(from OL) above Open Street Map (OSM()). I wanted a wind barb layer, for which I used [d3-wind-barb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-wind-barbs) from npm. I couldn't use it as style though it throws HTML objects in the console.

```
        layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
      }),
      new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: function (feature) {
          const wind = feature.get("wind");
          
          // using d3 windbarb
          var svg = new D3WindBarb(180, 50).draw("#container");
          console.log(svg);
          
          var svg_1 =
            "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," +
            '<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
            '<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60"/>' +
            "</svg>";

          console.log(svg_1);
          const outVal = new Style({
            image: new Icon({
              src: svg_1,
              // src: svg,  to be used when svg is set as source 
              size: 0.1,
            }),
          });
          return outVal;
        },
      }),
    ]
```

In this code when I try using src inside ICON as svg it doesn't work but when I use svg_1 the SVG is shown as a layer. During the console of svg and svg_1 the types are object and string respectively, but in both cases, they contain HTML tags.

How can I solve this problem? Additionally, I would be open to considering alternative methods for displaying wind barbs in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `D3WindBarb` docs (see https://ilsanchez.github.io/d3-wind-barbs/classes/d3windbarb.html#draw) your OL code to display `D3WindBarb` icon as vector layer style icon should look like something this:

```
new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    const wind = feature.get("wind");
    var svg = new D3WindBarb(180, 50, {
      size: {
        height: 20,
        width: 50
      }
    }).draw();
    const outVal = new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + svg.outerHTML,
      })
    });
    return outVal;
  },
})
```

It turned out that the above code does not work. After a lot of experimenting it turned out that some modification of SVG element created by `D3WindBarb` is needed.

This is code that works:

```
const windBarb = new D3WindBarb(
  86, // In knots. If your data is in other units you shuld pass de correct conversionFactor
  45, // in degrees
  // All this configuration is optional. Change it  or comment it to check its effects
  {
    bar: {
      angle: 30,
      fullBarClassName: "",
      padding: 6,
      shortBarClassName: "",
      stroke: "#000",
      width: 2
    },
    circle: {
      fill: "#FFFFFF00",
      stroke: "#000",
      radius: 10,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      className: "wind-barb-zero-knots-circle"
    },
    conversionFactor: ConversionFactors.None,
    rootBarClassName: "",
    size: {
      width: 80,
      height: 40
    },
    svgId: "",
    triangle: {
      fill: "#000",
      stroke: "#000",
      padding: 6,
      className: "wind-barb-triangle"
    },
    baseCircle: {
      className: "wind-barb-base-circle",
      fill: "#000",
      radius: 5,
      stroke: "#000",
      strokeWidth: 1
    }
  }
).draw();

windBarb.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
windBarb.setAttribute("xmlns:svg", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
windBarb.setAttribute("width", "40");
windBarb.setAttribute("height", "80");

const style = new Style({
   image: new Icon({
      opacity: 1,
     src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + window.encodeURIComponent(windBarb.outerHTML),
    })
});

const feature = new Feature(
  new Point(olProj.fromLonLat([14.5, 46]))
);

const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: [feature]
});
```

This is how the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: I tried the code but it still does not seem to work. It would be great if you have any other ideas to add wind barbs in OpenLayers.

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: Thank You for the code, it works.